# Where to request ACH Direct DEBIT of funds from MY OWN personal bank account?

Tags: united-states, banking, bank-account, online-banking, ach

Could anyone please explain where and how to request ACH Direct DEBIT of funds from MY OWN personal bank account? The ACH Processors such as nationalach.com are out of the question because they only work with business companies. Once i would like to send funds to someone else's PERSONAL account and once to someone else's BUSINESS account. Always via having my own funds on my own personal account ACH direct debited. I don't know where to request this. I did some research, my account is in Wells Fargo, and it might be possible to create ''ACH File'' but I have zero experiences in this. No idea how to do this, where to send that to, via what to sent,... How else can I request ach debit (own personal account with my own funds)?

(Note:
cannot send a check. Need solution to EXACT situation i am referring to. Not an alternative.)

Comment: What's wrong with sending a check?

Comment: If Wells Fargo, ask your "personal banker?"

Comment: This is strange wording, but my own wording would sound stranger to a banker. I have imagined there really should be such a thing as ACH PUSH to get money from one account to another. Basically, same as wiretransfer (which can already do this) but without the speed and $25 overhead.

Comment: @Joshua: "ACH Push" is the generally accepted term... usually appears in online banking as "external transfer".

Answer (score 4):

Call Wells Fargo or go to a branch.  Tell them what you're trying to accomplish, not the vehicle you think you should use to get there.  Don't tell them you want to ACH DEBIT from YOUR ACCOUNT of YOUR MONEY.  Tell them you apparently need a paperless transaction sent to this and that account at this and that bank.  See if they offer a solution.

Comment: And if you are doing this because someone else demands you do it this way, make sure their reason is a legitimate one. Any time someone tries to dictate an unusual payment method,  beware of a scam.